# Error 403: 'Request had insufficient authentication scopes' even though the relevant scopes are activated

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api

I am trying to build a basic script that can send emails from a Gmail account, with my code mostly coming from: https://ui.ads.microsoft.com/campaign/vnext/accounts/overview/expert?cid=19013943&uid=93024518

I have tried the common fixes I have found, like enabling the GMAIL API, authorizing the corresponding calls, currently authorized are namely:

- .../auth/gmail.send
- .../auth/docs
- .../auth/drive
- .../auth/drive.scripts
- .../auth/spreadsheets
- .../auth/gmail.modify
- .../auth/gmail.compose
- https://mail.google.com/

```
function main() {
    var MailApp = new Bing();    
    const notificationEmail = '**my-email**';
    var email = [
        `To: ${notificationEmail}`,
        'Subject: Google Services script',
        '',
        `You script ran successfully ✓`
    ].join('\n');
    MailApp.sendEmail(email);  
}


class Bing{
    constructor() {
        this.credentials = {

            accessToken: '',
            clientId: '**my-client-id**',
            clientSecret: '**my-client-secret**',
            refreshToken: '**my-refresh-token**'

        };
        this.gmailApi = GoogleApis.createGmailService(this.credentials);
    }
    sendEmail(email) {
    }
}


// ^ Basic Copy+Paste from tutorial mentioned above ^
var GoogleApis;
(function (GoogleApis) {
  function createGmailService(credentials) {
    return createService("https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest", credentials);
  }
  GoogleApis.createGmailService = createGmailService;
 
  // Creation logic based on https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/using#usage-simple
  function createService(url, credentials) {
    var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
    var discovery = JSON.parse(content);
    var baseUrl = discovery['rootUrl'] + discovery['servicePath'];
    var accessToken = getAccessToken(credentials);
    var service = build(discovery, {}, baseUrl, accessToken);
    return service;
  }
 
  function createNewMethod(method, baseUrl, accessToken) {
    return (urlParams, body) => {
      var urlPath = method.path;
      var queryArguments = [];
      for (var name in urlParams) {
        var paramConfg = method.parameters[name];
        if (!paramConfg) {
          throw `Unexpected url parameter ${name}`;
        }
        switch (paramConfg.location) {
          case 'path':
            urlPath = urlPath.replace('{' + name + '}', urlParams[name]);
            break;
          case 'query':
            queryArguments.push(`${name}=${urlParams[name]}`);
            break;
          default:
            throw `Unknown location ${paramConfg.location} for url parameter ${name}`;
        }
      }
      var url = baseUrl + urlPath;
      if (queryArguments.length > 0) {
        url += '?' + queryArguments.join('&');
      }
      var httpResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { contentType: 'application/json', method: method.httpMethod, payload: JSON.stringify(body), headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` }, muteHttpExceptions: true });
      var responseContent = httpResponse.getContentText();
      var responseCode = httpResponse.getResponseCode();
      var parsedResult;
      try {
        parsedResult = JSON.parse(responseContent);
      } catch (e) {
        parsedResult = false;
      }
      var response = new Response(parsedResult, responseContent, responseCode);
      if (responseCode >= 200 && responseCode <= 299) {
        return response;
      }
      throw response;
    }
  }

    function Response(result, body, status) {
    this.result = result;
    this.body = body;
    this.status = status;
  }
  Response.prototype.toString = function () {
    return this.body;
  }
 
  function build(discovery, collection, baseUrl, accessToken) {
    for (var name in discovery.resources) {
      var resource = discovery.resources[name];
      collection[name] = build(resource, {}, baseUrl, accessToken);
    }
    for (var name in discovery.methods) {
      var method = discovery.methods[name];
      collection[name] = createNewMethod(method, baseUrl, accessToken);
    }
    return collection;
  }
 
  function getAccessToken(credentials) {
    if (credentials.accessToken) {
      return credentials.accessToken;
    }
    var tokenResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token', { method: 'post', contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', muteHttpExceptions: true, payload: { client_id: credentials.clientId, client_secret: credentials.clientSecret, refresh_token: credentials.refreshToken, grant_type: 'refresh_token' } });    
    var responseCode = tokenResponse.getResponseCode(); 
    var responseText = tokenResponse.getContentText(); 
    if (responseCode >= 200 && responseCode <= 299) {
      var accessToken = JSON.parse(responseText)['access_token'];
      return accessToken;
    }    
    throw responseText;  
  }
})(GoogleApis || (GoogleApis = {}));

class Base64 {
  static encode(input) {
    const keyStr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
    let output = "";
    let chr1, chr2, chr3, enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
    var i = 0;
    input = this.utf8Encode(input);
    while (i < input.length) {
      chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
      chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
      chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
      enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
      enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
      enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
      enc4 = chr3 & 63;
      if (isNaN(chr2)) {
        enc3 = enc4 = 64;
      }
      else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
        enc4 = 64;
      }
      output = output + keyStr.charAt(enc1) + keyStr.charAt(enc2) + keyStr.charAt(enc3) + keyStr.charAt(enc4);
    }
    return output.replace(/\+/g, "-").replace(/\//g, "_").replace(/=+$/, "");
  }
  static utf8Encode(input) {
    input = input.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");
    var utftext = "";
    for (var n = 0; n < input.length; n++) {
      var c = input.charCodeAt(n);
      if (c < 128) {
        utftext += String.fromCharCode(c);
      }
      else if ((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
        utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 6) | 192);
        utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
      }
      else {
        utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 12) | 224);
        utftext += String.fromCharCode(((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);
        utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
      }
    }
    return utftext;
  }
}
```

I have gotten the OAuth2 from google using option 2 from this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/scripts/examples/authenticating-with-google-services

The scopes are correctly enabled, namely the .../auth/gmail.send

still I get the following error:

```
{
"error": {
"code": 403,
"message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
"errors": [
{
"message": "Insufficient Permission",
"domain": "global",
"reason": "insufficientPermissions"
}
],
"status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
}
```

Comment: where are you adding that scope in your code i dont see it.

Answer (score 1):

I cant see anywhere in your code that you are supplying a scope you should try following [JS quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Gmail API Quickstart</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Gmail API Quickstart</p>

    <!--Add buttons to initiate auth sequence and sign out-->
    <button id="authorize_button" style="display: none;">Authorize</button>
    <button id="signout_button" style="display: none;">Sign Out</button>

    <pre id="content" style="white-space: pre-wrap;"></pre>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Client ID and API key from the Developer Console
      var CLIENT_ID = '<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>';
      var API_KEY = '<YOUR_API_KEY>';

      // Array of API discovery doc URLs for APIs used by the quickstart
      var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest"];

      // Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
      // included, separated by spaces.
      var SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly';

      var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize_button');
      var signoutButton = document.getElementById('signout_button');

      /**
       *  On load, called to load the auth2 library and API client library.
       */
      function handleClientLoad() {
        gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
      }

      /**
       *  Initializes the API client library and sets up sign-in state
       *  listeners.
       */
      function initClient() {
        gapi.client.init({
          apiKey: API_KEY,
          clientId: CLIENT_ID,
          discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
          scope: SCOPES
        }).then(function () {
          // Listen for sign-in state changes.
          gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

          // Handle the initial sign-in state.
          updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
          authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
          signoutButton.onclick = handleSignoutClick;
        }, function(error) {
          appendPre(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
        });
      }

      /**
       *  Called when the signed in status changes, to update the UI
       *  appropriately. After a sign-in, the API is called.
       */
      function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
          authorizeButton.style.display = 'none';
          signoutButton.style.display = 'block';
          listLabels();
        } else {
          authorizeButton.style.display = 'block';
          signoutButton.style.display = 'none';
        }
      }

      /**
       *  Sign in the user upon button click.
       */
      function handleAuthClick(event) {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
      }

      /**
       *  Sign out the user upon button click.
       */
      function handleSignoutClick(event) {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
      }

      /**
       * Append a pre element to the body containing the given message
       * as its text node. Used to display the results of the API call.
       *
       * @param {string} message Text to be placed in pre element.
       */
      function appendPre(message) {
        var pre = document.getElementById('content');
        var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
        pre.appendChild(textContent);
      }

      /**
       * Print all Labels in the authorized user's inbox. If no labels
       * are found an appropriate message is printed.
       */
      function listLabels() {
        gapi.client.gmail.users.labels.list({
          'userId': 'me'
        }).then(function(response) {
          var labels = response.result.labels;
          appendPre('Labels:');

          if (labels && labels.length > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
              var label = labels[i];
              appendPre(label.name)
            }
          } else {
            appendPre('No Labels found.');
          }
        });
      }

    </script>

    <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
      onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
      onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```